# Pagination for Reading Titan Vertex from HBase

Tags: hbase, titan

I am currently working on creating a Java code that can read Titan Vertex From from Hadoop HBase backend. I know blueprint api provides a getVertices() method on every TransactionalGraph, but still I am trying implement my own method. Now for usual vertex reading I already a working code that can read the entire HBase backend and fetch all the vertices from Titan Graph, but I am having a problem in implementing Pagination.

My Code so far :

```
    Scan scan = new Scan();
    Filter pageFilter = new ColumnPaginationFilter(DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE, currentOffSet);
    scan.setFilter(pageFilter);
    scan.addFamily(Backend.EDGESTORE_NAME.getBytes());
    scan.setMaxVersions(10);
    List<Vertex> vertexList = new ArrayList<>(DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE);
    HTablePool pool = new HTablePool(config, DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE);
    ResultScanner scanner = pool.getTable(attributeMap.get("storage.tablename")).getScanner(scan);
```

But the ResultScanner returning the entire Graph.

**currentOffSet** is a int variable which determines the Current Page Number.

I also tried with *ResultScanner#next(int rowCount)*. It works fine. But in this process I don't have an option to Go Back to Previous Page.

Can any one help me ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. The logic is pretty simple. You have to use the **setStartRow** method on the scanner instance. For the first time it is not necessary because the scanning should be started from the very first row. Then we need to fetch *(PAGE_SIZE+1)* numbers of rows. The last row from the **ResultScanner** will be used as the starting row for the next Page.

For going back to Previous page we need to use a buffer or stack that will store the **starting row** for all the previously visited page.

Here is my Code snippet :

```
    Scan scan = (new Scan()).addFamily(Backend.EDGESTORE_NAME.getBytes());
    Filter filter = new PageFilter(DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE + 1);
    scan.setFilter(filter);
    if (currentPageStartRowForHBase != null) {
        scan.setStartRow(currentPageStartRowForHBase);
    }
    List<Vertex> vertexList = new ArrayList<>(DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE + 1);
    HTablePool pool = null;
    ResultScanner scanner = null;
    try {
        if (pool == null) {
            pool = new HTablePool(config, DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE + 1);

        }
        scanner = pool.getTable(attributeMap.get("storage.tablename")).getScanner(scan);
        for (Result result : scanner) {
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(result.getRow());
            Vertex vertex = this.getVertex(IDHandler.getKeyID(byteBuffer));
            if (vertexList.size() < DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE)
                vertexList.add(vertex);
            else {
                nextPageStartRowForHBase = byteBuffer.array();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**nextPageStartRowForHBase** & **currentPageStartRowForHBase** are **byte[]**.

This fulfilled my requirement. But If anyone have any better solution please share with us.

Comment: I just started evaluating Titan and my understanding was that once cannot directly read/write Titan graph data from Hbase. It looks like you are saying it is possible. Could you point me to examples that can show me how to do this?

Comment: The above code is the simplest example of what you are asking. The List<Vertex> vertexList is the Collection that I used to hold the Vertices.
`IDHandler.getKeyID(byteBuffer)`

This line actually returns the vertex id from the HBase backend. Now once I get the vertex id, It's not much complicated to get The Vertex Instance. 

What I needed was a simple way to read Data from HBase Backend and Cassandra because Titan do not support Global Query. If you want a better way to read data from HBase or Cassandra you can definitely do it by exploring the Back-end functionality.